# issue related to iview table in data rendering

Tags: node.js, vue.js

if i have data object like to this

```
data: [ { name: { nikeName: 'sam', realName: 'sanjay' }, age: 18, address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park', date: '2016-10-03' }, { name: { nikeName: 'roy', realName: 'ravindra' }, age: 24, address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park', date: '2016-10-01' } ]
```

then how can i display nikeName/realName from the KEY name in iview table

i have tried this

```
columns1: [ { title: 'Name', key: 'name.nikeName' // name.realName }, { title: 'Age', key: 'age' }, { title: 'Address', key: 'address' } ],
```

but it is not working.

is there any way to display this type of object data?

Comment: Is it possible to share live demo ? In vuejs

Comment: Yes here i have created an example -----> https://jsfiddle.net/qoboxqkq/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested objects and array using render method.

Here i have attached solution.

Let me know if you have any query.

```
render: (h, params) => {
  return h('div', [
    h('strong', ' '+params.row.name.nikName)
  ]);
}
```

[JsFiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaviii/w8jv1wwL/)